# active record grouping and sum with json data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I'm using Rails 4.1, Ruby 2.1 and the groupdate gem 2.4

I have a records table with these columns:

:value (json) :day (datetime)

current_user.time_zone gives the users' time zone.

value gives a json object like this:

```
{"430"=>1079.27, "400"=>10.23 }
```

I'm trying to add up all the value['430'] fields for each week

This gives an error

```
Record.where(:user_id => current_user.id).group_by_week(:day, time_zone: current_user.time_zone).sum("value#>>'{430}'")


   (40.3ms)  SELECT SUM(value#>>'{430}') AS sum_value_430, (DATE_TRUNC('week', (day::timestamptz - INTERVAL '6 day' - INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai') + INTERVAL '6 day' + INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai' AS week FROM "eats"  WHERE "eats"."user_id" = 53 AND (day IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (DATE_TRUNC('week', (day::timestamptz - INTERVAL '6 day' - INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai') + INTERVAL '6 day' + INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai'
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function sum(text) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT SUM(value#>>'{430}') AS sum_total_nutr...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT SUM(value#>>'{430}') AS sum_value_430, (DATE_TRUNC('week', (day::timestamptz - INTERVAL '6 day' - INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai') + INTERVAL '6 day' + INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai' AS week FROM "eats"  WHERE "eats"."user_id" = 53 AND (day IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (DATE_TRUNC('week', (day::timestamptz - INTERVAL '6 day' - INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai') + INTERVAL '6 day' + INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function sum(text) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT SUM(value#>>'{430}') AS sum_total_nutr...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT SUM(value#>>'{430}') AS sum_value_430, (DATE_TRUNC('week', (day::timestamptz - INTERVAL '6 day' - INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai') + INTERVAL '6 day' + INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai' AS week FROM "eats"  WHERE "eats"."user_id" = 53 AND (day IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (DATE_TRUNC('week', (day::timestamptz - INTERVAL '6 day' - INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai') + INTERVAL '6 day' + INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai'
```

After trying

```
Record.where(:user_id => current_user.id).group_by_week(:day, time_zone: current_user.time_zone).sum("CAST(value->>'430'AS integer)")
```

I got

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid at /records
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "1063.32"
: SELECT SUM(CAST(value->>'430'AS integer)) AS sum_cast_value_430_as_integer, (DATE_TRUNC('week', (day::timestamptz - INTERVAL '6 day' - INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai') + INTERVAL '6 day' + INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai' AS week FROM "records"  WHERE "records"."user_id" = 53 AND (day IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (DATE_TRUNC('week', (day::timestamptz - INTERVAL '6 day' - INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai') + INTERVAL '6 day' + INTERVAL '0' hour) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai'
```

Answer (score 3):

You perhaps need to cast the JSON typed field to an integer (I've removed the other query methods for clarity).

```
Record.sum("CAST(value->>'430'AS integer)")
```

Comment: I got an error. Also I need it to cast to a decimal or float. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I decided to change the architecture so that the value was available to query without searching through the json

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
value = Record.where(:user_id => current_user.id).group_by_week(:day, time_zone: current_user.time_zone).pluck(:value)
sum = value.reduce(:+)
```

Comment: `pluck()` wouldn't work in this case, since `value` is not a column in the database, but a field within a JSON typed column in the database.